# nested collections with POJO

Tags: java, mybatis

I am trying to follow the same methods listed in this blog [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/ibatis-mybatis-handling-joins) to avoid the N+1 problem.
I have created 5 classes with a many to 1 relationship as follows:

Trunk -> Branch 1 -> Branch 2 -> Branch 3 ->Leaf

I am trying to build my XML mapper which complies but fails at runtime with an error that there is no property 'Branch2' in 'class com.mytest.branch1'

I have defined my XML mapper as

```
<mapper namespace="com.mytest.test">
  <resultMap id="resultTest" type="com.mytest.test.trunk">
     <id property="TrunkID" column="TRUNK_ID" />
     <collection property="Branch1" column="BRANCH_1_ID" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="com.mytest.test.branch1">
       <id property="branch1ID" column="BRANCH_1_ID">
       <collection property="Branch2" column="BRANCH_2" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="com.mytest.test.branch2">
         <id property="branch2ID" column="BRANCH_2_ID">
         <collection property="Branch3" column="BRANCH_3" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="com.mytest.test.branch3">
           <id property="branch3ID" column="BRANCH_3_ID">
           <result property="Value" column="Value">
         </collection>
       </collection>
     </collection>
  </resultMap>
  <select id="getAllNodes" resultMap="resultTest">
    select n.TRUNK_ID,b.BRANCH_1_ID,b.BRANCH_2_ID,b.BRANCH_3_ID,b.VALUE FROM node n join branches b on n.node_id=b.node_id
  </select>
</mapper>
```

Class Trunk:

```
public class Trunk {

private int TrunkID;
private List<Branch1> Branch1;


//getters and setters
}
```

Class Branch1:

```
public class Branch1{

private int Branch1ID;
private List<Branch2> Branch2;

//getters and setters ...
}
```

Class Branch2:

```
public class Branch2{

private int Branch2ID;
private List<Branch3> Branch3;

//getters and setters ...
}
```

Class Branch3:

```
public class Branch3{

private int Branch3ID;

//getters and setters ...
}
```

Comment: please show us `branch1`, `branch2`, `branch3` classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things here.

---

**First**, did you even try to **compile** your code?
`BranchX` classes (and `Trunk`, too) don't have names for `List` fields.
It should look like this:

```
public class Trunk {
    private int TrunkID;
    private List<Branch1> listOfBranches;   // name added
}
```

So please fix `Trunk`, `Branch1` and `Branch2` to follow the abouve example.

---

**The second thing** is that nested `<collection>`s don't work this way.
Please refer to [the docs](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#association). 
They say:

> **`property:`** The field or property to map the column result to. If a matching JavaBeans property exists for the given name, then that will be used. Otherwise, MyBatis will look for a field of the given name.

So if you write

```
<collection property="Branch1" column="BRANCH_1_ID" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="com.mytest.test.branch1">
   <id property="branch1ID" column="BRANCH_1_ID">
   <collection property="Branch2" column="BRANCH_2" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="com.mytest.test.branch2">
    ...
   </collection>
</collection>
```

the outer `<collection>` element is ArrayList of `Branch1`.
It has two inner elements:

- `<id>` which is correctly mapped to `branch1ID` field in `Branch1` class
- `<collection>` which is supposed to be mapped to `Branch2` field in `Branch1` class - which is not existing.

Suggested fix for this is to name all `List` fields in your classes adequately, i.e:

```
public class Trunk {
    private int TrunkID;
    private List<Branch1> branch1;
}

public class Branch1{
    private int Branch1ID;
    private List<Branch2> branch2;
}
```

etc.

Hope that helps to understand what the problem was.

Comment: sorry I am obfuscating my code a bit...I will correct the question.